# Showing comments for a question should not fail a "first answer, known to be good" audit

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

So [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2636011) came up. It was clearly not a crap answer, and I could tell it was probably an audit because no username was being displayed, but I wanted to read the question before deciding whether to "no action" or "skip". The question had slightly fuddled grammar so I decided to look at its comments. The comment expansion text read "show 8 more comments" (all 8 comments were hidden). I clicked it and it failed the audit.

Why should an audit based on a known good answer fail because I was attempting to get more information on the question?

Interestingly enough, several non-audit reviews I've seen replace the "add comment"/"show more comments" link with the text "comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews". At the very least this text should have shown for this audit.

Comment: This is a bug, plain and simple.

The natural inclination of a good reviewer should be to get more information about the post before making a decision, if they're not sure.  Clicking on "show 8 more comments" should not ever be punitive.

Comment: Wow. How long has [disputed-review-audits] existed?

Comment: A month I guess, @Bolt? Just noticed it myself. Great way to make sure a bug with [tag:review] doesn't get noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent changes to the comments mechanism may have caused this problem, but question comments weren't supposed to render in this situation anyway.  This is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've reproduced this. It confused me at first, because we explicitly designed these audits to *not show any comments* - but it looks like we neglected to strip the comments from the *question* on audits where an *answer* was displayed. Clicking "show" triggers the same action as clicking "add comment" normally, which is considered a negative action.

[image: show more comments link]

Note that for audit-answers to questions *without* any comments, the link appears like this:

[image: comments disabled]

Clicking it neither fails nor passes the test.

Comment: why is commenting on a good post considered to be an audit fail? Are comments assumed to be negative in all cases?

Comment: Comments are assumed to be negative in the context of a review, yes.

Comment: @Shog9, thanks for the explanation. I just ran into this and as a new reviewer I was unaware that comments are assumed to be negative.