# Make Review Audits more Friendly

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits

I often click on add comment before actually reviewing, then decide whether or not to say anything. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3245144) audit, I followed my habit and click on "Add Comment" and was immediately slammed with a "STOP..." message. It feels so harsh for not doing anything.

A possible solution is to change the audit so that you only fail an audit when you click on "No Action Needed" / "I'm Done" or actually post a comment.

[I'm not alone (see Kate Gregory's comment).](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191459/showing-comments-for-a-question-should-not-fail-a-first-answer-known-to-be-goo/193265#comment604999_193265)

Comment: You might want to take a look at ["STOP! Look and Listen" audit tricked me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156938/stop-look-and-listen-audit-tricked-me).