# Is adding comments to apparently good quality answers inappropriate?

Tags: discussion, new-users, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I came across [this answer in the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts#first-posts/4037737?&_suid=139219161834709807423973431111):

> Sort the other range only, and then use [std::merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge).

I thought, that answer **may** be the solution, but instead of simply posting a link, the AP should elaborate a bit, adding even the smallest code example in case the linked resource ceases to exist.

When I did that, I saw the **Big Bad Blame Screen of Death**:

> ### STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You
> didn't pass**. Your review was **inappropriate**. This was a high
> quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even
> upvoting.

OK, is adding a comment something **so bad** that I should be ashamed of trying to do that with so highly upvoted answer? Maybe it's time to fix review audits a bit?

**--edit--** I've [added my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21592350/531954) anyway!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191459/showing-comments-for-a-question-should-not-fail-a-first-answer-known-to-be-goo

Comment: @psubsee2003 however, this shows a specific case where a comment _was_ appropriate.

Comment: @JanDvorak it was a bad review, yes, but that's been discussed to death too.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian than what's the point of enabling comments/votes in review queue if it should not be used? The system expects me to take **any** action, or just hit 'It's OK'. In that case, it wasn't OK, otherwise I wouldn't be here.