# Will upvoting a comment make me fail an audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

After [failing an audit by trying to add comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220694/is-adding-comments-to-apparently-good-quality-answers-inappropriate) and [recent review ban without explanation what I've failed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223384/could-you-at-least-give-me-a-hint-what-recent-audits-ive-failed) I'm going a bit paranoical about audits.

Could you say me, if upvoting any comment would make me to fail an audit? I see some answers in first posts review queue, that are of not very high quality, but there's something useful in them and there's a comment for AP, what should be improved. In that case, I think that voting to delete the answer would be too harsh and not very educative for new user, while upvoting the comment would give him a valuable hint what to improve.

Note: I'm not speaking about chatty or link-only answers, I'm speaking about answers containing some useful information, but requiring improvement from AP.

Comment: I think there should be nothing bad with upvoting a comment, if it is a good comment